# How to use Lookups that span relationships in Django

Tags: django, rest, filtering, django-queryset

I have models User, Store, Warehouse and Product.
I need to get all products from the warehouse.
User have a lot of stores. One store have a lot of warehouses.
А product with the same identifier (SKU) can be stored in different warehouses.

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(
            warehouse__store__user_id=self.request.user.pk)\
            .order_by('-offer_id')
```

Am I right to filter products such way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right to filter products such way?

That depends on the value given to the [**`related_query_name=…`** parameters <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) of the `ForeignKey`s, `ManyToManyField`s and `OneToOneField`. If you do not specify a value for the `related_query_name=…`, it will take the value you pass to the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), and if you did not specify such paramete,r it will fallback to the name of the model in lowercase.

If there is thus a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` form `Warehouse` to `Product` for example, and you did *not* specify a `related_query_name=…` or `related_name=…`, it will take `warehouse` as query name, and you thus can follow the relation with the `__warehouse` lookup. You can recurse on that, and thus then pick the relation from the warehouse.

The query looks correct, you can simplify this however to:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Product.objects.filter(
        warehouse__store__user=self.request.user
    ).order_by('-offer_id')
```